# Selenium hub freezes when a test is a launched on a node

Tags: selenium, server

I've a selenium server instance running with following parameters:

```
java -DPOOL_MAX=512 -Xmx2G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:ParallelCMSThreads=2 -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8090 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -cp /jhub/_prod/server_ptiqaaeryn_selenium_daemon/lib/*:/jhub/_prod/server_ptiqaaeryn_selenium_daemon/lib/.:/jhub/_prod/server_ptiqaaeryn_selenium_daemon/conf/. org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher -port 4444 -role hub -hubConfig /jhub/_prod/server_ptiqaaeryn_selenium_daemon/conf/hub.json
```

hub json contains following

```
{
  "host": 10.1.22.116,
  "port": 4444,
  "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
  "servlets" : [],
  "prioritizer": null,
  "capabilityMatcher": "com.buongiorno.qa.crais.idCapabilityMatcher",
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
  "timeout": 300000,
  "browserTimeout": 5000,
  "maxSession": 50,
  "jettyMaxThreads": -1,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "downPollingLimit": 2,
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 5000
}
```

every time a node fails to answer to hub requests I obtain following error

```
 INFO 2015-06-29 12:31:18,679 [Probing status of http://10.57.11.11:4739/wd/hub/status][] execchain.RetryExec:execute(94) - I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {}->http://10.57.11.11:4739: The target server failed to respond
DEBUG 2015-06-29 12:31:18,688 [Probing status of http://10.57.11.11:4739/wd/hub/status][] execchain.RetryExec:execute(101) - The target server failed to respond
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:161)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:115)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.openqa.grid.internal.BaseRemoteProxy.getStatus(BaseRemoteProxy.java:516)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.beta.WebProxyHtmlRendererBeta.getHtmlNodeVersion(WebProxyHtmlRendererBeta.java:78)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.beta.WebProxyHtmlRendererBeta.renderSummary(WebProxyHtmlRendererBeta.java:54)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.beta.ConsoleServlet.process(ConsoleServlet.java:128)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.beta.ConsoleServlet.doGet(ConsoleServlet.java:63)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:565)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:479)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:225)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1031)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:965)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.Server.handle(Server.java:345)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:452)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:47)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:884)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:634)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:66)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:254)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 DEBUG 2015-06-29 12:31:18,677 [Probing status of http://10.57.11.11:4739/wd/hub/status][] execchain.ConnectionHolder:abortConnection(126) - Connection discarded
```

and hub freezes.
Hub restarts working only if turn off the node,  otherwise at

```
 http://10.1.22.116:4444/grid/console
```

page is not responding.

I suppose some of my hub.json parameters are misconfigured otherwise a node that is not responding should not hang the whole hub.
My first goal is not understand why a node is not responding but to understand avoid that a failing node lay waste to the whole hub.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must increase the Browser_Timeout parameter in your JSON. 5000 is 5 seconds. So if the Node doesn't replies for 5 seconds, it will throw this error, and then mark that particular node as gone.